# Verificar se elemento existe com seletor jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Porquê isso,

```
if (typeof($("div#elementoquenãoexiste")) !== "undefined") { console.log("existe");  }
```

retorna `"existe"` nos logs? Não deveria retornar `undefined`, levando em consideração que o elemento que o seletor indica não existe?

Ou será que, por estar envolvido numa função do jQuery (`$()`) ele venha a ser definido já que possui funções/propriedades atrelhadas a ele, mesmo que o seletor aponte para um elemento que não existe na DOM.  Estou certo?

Preciso de uma noção correta do que está acontecendo neste caso, obrigado!

Comment: Acho que queres fazer `if ($("div#elementoquenãoexiste").length) { console.log("existe");  }`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O que queres usar é a [propriedade `.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) que indica o numero de elementos no objecto jQuery.

```
if ($("div#elementoquenãoexiste").length) { console.log("existe"); }
```

O jQuery retorna sempre um objecto. Seja um seletor, uma array, etc, ele retorna sempre um objeto. Quando usas

```
if (typeof($("div#elementoquenãoexiste")) !== "undefined") { console.log("existe");  }
```

estás a verificar se `typeof {} !== "undefined"` o que dá sempre verdadeiro.

Dá uma olhada na consola deste exemplo: **https://jsfiddle.net/dnkgqycg/**

O que vais ver é:

```
console.log($()); // []
console.log($(false)); // []
console.log($(0)); // []
console.log($([1, 2, 3])); // [1, 2, 3] 
console.log($('#eunaoexisto')); // objeto jQuery
console.log($('#eunaoexisto').length); // 0 <---- este é o unico com valor Booleano FALSE
console.log($('#euexisto')); // objeto jQuery 
console.log($('#euexisto').length); // 1
```